How to organize the header elements, so that it doesn't come out differentin mobile view

Hi this is the website where its been stacking the columns in mobile view.
https://ebenmission.org.au/
Because there are so many elements, I've been manually adjusting it rather than editing it in a coding way as elements kept on getting mixed up in the different views.
Tablet view still looks ok as well but the problem is the mobile view.
I've been adjusting the width, and everytime I change or add columns to make icons stay on the same line, it messes the desktop view also.

Is there a way to return the columns as a normal column instead of rows for just the mobile view?
What's the button I need to press to make it appear in the same line?


